# Arrange the Polynomial in Canonical Order in C

Tags: c, sorting, struct, linked-list, polynomials

Let's say I have a Polynomial with 3 variables (x, y, z) that is not necessarily in canonical order and I want it to be in standard form where the leftmost term has the greatest exponent and the rightmost term has the least exponent. For example case:

Original Polynomial:
`-7xy⁶ + 9xz - 8y⁷ +x⁷ + 4x⁵y⁴z² + 4xy²z³ + 3xy³`

Standard Form:
`x⁷ + 4x⁵y³z² - 7xy⁶ + 3xy³ + 4xy²z³ + 9xz - 8y⁷`

This can be easily done in Python, but I am in C and I have no idea how it should be done. Here is a sample code where I implement polynomials with `struct`. To make it look less confusing, I am not displaying the variables. Instead, my format is: `x exponent` `y exponent` `z exponent` `coefficient`. Example: `4(x^5)(y^3)(z^2)` is `5 3 2 4`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct Node
{
    int coeff;
    int powX;
    int powY;
    int powZ;
    struct Node* next;
};

void readPolynomial(struct Node** poly)      /* ACCEPTS A POLYNOMIAL WITH N TERMS */
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    *poly = temp;

    int terms;
    scanf("%d\n", &terms);

    for(int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        char entry[200];
        fgets(entry, sizeof(entry), stdin);;
        char * splitter;
        splitter = strtok(entry," ");
        temp->powX = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->powY = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->powZ = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->coeff = atoi(splitter);
        temp->next = NULL;
        if(i != terms-1)
        {
            temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
}

void canonicalPolynomial(struct Node* poly)
{
    while(poly != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n", poly->powX, poly->powY, poly->powZ, poly->coeff);
        poly = poly->next;
    }
}

int main()
{

    struct Node* result = NULL;

    readPolynomial(&result);
    canonicalPolynomial(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Right now, `canonicalPolynomial` just prints it in the said format, but not yet in canonical order.

Input:

```
7
1 6 0 -7
1 0 1 9
0 7 0 -8
7 0 0 1
5 3 2 4
1 2 3 4
1 3 0 3
```

Expected Output:

```
7 0 0 1
5 3 2 4
1 6 0 -7
1 3 0 3
1 2 3 4
1 0 1 9
0 7 0 -8
```

**UPDATE: Here's my latest code. I get the given test code right, but I miss the hidden ones in our compiler. So far, my code knows when a term has the coefficient `0`, it does not print it. What else could I be missing?**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Node
{
    float coeff;
    int powX;
    int powY;
    int powZ;
    struct Node* next;
};


void readPolynomial(struct Node** poly)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    *poly = temp;

    int terms;
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &terms);
    getchar();

    char entry[999999];
    char *splitter;
    for(int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        fgets(entry, sizeof(entry), stdin);
        splitter = strtok(entry," ");
        temp->powX = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->powY = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->powZ = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->coeff = atof(splitter);
        temp->next = NULL;
        if(i != terms-1)
        {
            temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
}

int compareTerms(const struct Node *a, const struct Node *b)
{
    int cmp;

    cmp = (a->powX > b->powX) - (a->powX < b->powX);
    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }
    cmp = (a->powY > b->powY) - (a->powY < b->powY);
    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }
    cmp = (a->powZ > b->powZ) - (a->powZ < b->powZ);
    return cmp;
}

void sortPolynomialTerms(struct Node **poly)
{
    struct Node *head;
    unsigned int sublen;

    head = *poly;
    if (!head) {

        return;
    }

    sublen = 1;
    while (1) {
        struct Node *tail;
        struct Node *p;
        struct Node *q;
        struct Node *e;
        unsigned int plen;
        unsigned int qlen;
        unsigned int merges;
        unsigned int i;

        p = head;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        merges = 0;
        while (p) {
            merges++;
            q = p;
            plen = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < sublen; i++) {
                plen++;
                q = q->next;
                if (!q) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            qlen = plen;

            while (plen || (qlen && q)) {
                if (!plen || (qlen && q && compareTerms(p, q) < 0)) {
                    e = q;
                    q = q->next;
                    qlen--;
                } else {
                    e = p;
                    p = p->next;
                    plen--;
                }
                if (tail) {
                    tail->next = e;
                } else {
                    head = e;
                }
                tail = e;
            }

            p = q;
        }
        tail->next = NULL;

        if (merges <= 1) {
            break;
        }

        sublen *= 2;
    }

    *poly = head;
}

void printPolynomial(const struct Node *poly)
{
    while (poly)
    {
        if(poly->coeff != 0)
        {
                printf("%d %d %d %.3f\n", poly->powX, poly->powY, poly->powZ, poly->coeff);
        }
        poly = poly->next;
    }
}

void canonicalPolynomial(struct Node **poly)
{
    sortPolynomialTerms(poly);
    printPolynomial(*poly);
}

void addPolynomials(struct Node** result, struct Node* first, struct Node* second)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->next = NULL;
    *result = temp;
    while(first && second)
    {
        if(compareTerms(first, second) < 0)
        {
            temp->coeff = second->coeff;
            temp->powX = second->powX;
            temp->powY = second->powY;
            temp->powZ = second->powZ;
            second = second->next;

        }
        else if(compareTerms(first, second) > 0)
        {
            temp->coeff = first->coeff;
            temp->powX = first->powX;
            temp->powY = first->powY;
            temp->powZ = first->powZ;
            first = first->next;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->coeff = first->coeff + second->coeff;
            temp->powX = first->powX;
            temp->powY = first->powY;
            temp->powZ = first->powZ;
            first = first->next;
            second = second->next;
        }
        if(first && second)
        {
            temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    while(first || second)
    {
        temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if(second)
        {
            temp->coeff = second->coeff;
            temp->powX = second->powX;
            temp->powY = second->powY;
            temp->powZ = second->powZ;
            second = second->next;
        }

        else if(first)
        {
            temp->coeff = first->coeff;
            temp->powX = first->powX;
            temp->powY = first->powY;
            temp->powZ = first->powZ;
            first = first->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* first = NULL;
    struct Node* second = NULL;
    struct Node* result = NULL;

    readPolynomial(&first);
    readPolynomial(&second);
    addPolynomials(&result, first, second);
    canonicalPolynomial(&result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `4x^5y^3z^2 + ... + 4xy^2z^3` looks like gibberish.

Comment: Which is why I am not gonna display the variables. I am using the format `x exponent` `y exponent` `z exponent` `coefficient` for every term. I just wish you can format math equations in this site to make it look less gibberish.

Comment: Your mathematical term itself is gibberish. You can't write `w^x^y^z`. What shall that mean? Do you mean `w^(x^(y^z))`? PS even if you mean something like this, this is not a polynominal standard form.

Comment: Ahh, yes. I was not expecting it could be interpreted the exponential way. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: The last solution was actually helpful.

Comment: You have to sort an array of `Node` values into decreasing order of `x` exponents, and when the `x` exponents are equal, in descending order of `y` exponents, and when the `x` and `y` exponents are equal, in descending order of `z` exponents. If all the exponents are the same, there's a bug in the polynomial — the two terms should be combined into one, but that should probably happen before you start sorting. I suppose you can sort by coefficient too instead. And after sorting, you can compare adjacent `Node` values for equal exponents and combine them then; it may be more efficient like that.

Comment: @lambduh I was answering how to normalize a polynomial. Not how to write it in standard form. That's why I deleted it. But your problem boils down to sorting a linked list, and that is a problem that there exists thousands of solutions to.

Comment: I guess it was my mistake to mention "standard form". Anyway, what I'm really asking is how to arrange it in canonical order. If that clears things.

Comment: @lambduh Nevertheless, my answer did not produce what you're asking for.

Comment: Your degree function actually reduced my code. I'm trying to build a bubble sort which I will show after I finish.

Comment: Update: I added a bubble sort-ish approach of sorting the entered polynomial but the output is kind of messed up. What's wrong with my bubble sort?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use the standard `qsort` defined in `stdlib.h`? It's probably faster and less work.

Comment: You are not supposed to keep replacing the code in the question.

Comment: Rolled back  to the most relevant version where my code was not edited. I added my current code at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem boils down to sorting a linked list, for which you need a suitable comparison function to determine the sort order for two terms on the list:

```
int compareTerms(const struct Node *a, const struct Node *b)
{
    int cmp;

    /* Compare X exponents. */
    cmp = (a->powX > b->powX) - (a->powX < b->powX);
    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }
    /* Compare Y exponents. */
    cmp = (a->powY > b->powY) - (a->powY < b->powY);
    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }
    /* Compare Z exponents. */
    cmp = (a->powZ > b->powZ) - (a->powZ < b->powZ);
#if 0
    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }
    /* Compare coefficients (why not?). */
    cmp = (a->coeff > b->coeff) - (a->coeff < b->coeff);
#endif
    return cmp;
}
```

(Change the `#if 0` to `#if 1` to compare the coefficients if all the exponents are equal.)

The function returns -1 if the first term has lower order than the second, 1 if the first term has higher order than the second, or 0 if they are of equal order.

The comparison function can be used by a function to sort the list of terms. For simplicity, an exchange sort is shown below:

```
void sortPolynomialTerms(struct Node **poly)
{
    while (*poly) {
        struct Node **next = &(*poly)->next;
        while (*next) {
            struct Node *n = *next;
            if (compareTerms(*poly, n) < 0) {
                *next = n->next;
                n->next = *poly;
                *poly = n;
            } else {
                next = &n->next;
            }
        }
        poly = &(*poly)->next;
    }
}
```

The sort function can be used as follows:

```
void printPolynomial(const struct Node *poly)
{
    while (poly)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d %.3f\n", poly->powX, poly->powY, poly->powZ, poly->coeff);
        poly = poly->next;
    }
}

void canonicalPolynomial(struct Node **poly)
{
    sortPolynomialTerms(poly);
    printPolynomial(*poly);
}
```

The parameter of `sortPolynomialTerms` and `canonicalPolynomial` is `struct Node **poly` because they may modify the pointer to the initial term `*poly` to point to a different initial term.

---

**BONUS CONTENT**

It is probably not worth it for short polynomials, but for polynomials containing many terms to be sorted, a merge sort will be more efficient than the exchange sort implemented above. Based on the sample code "[listsort.c](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/algorithms/listsort.c)" for the page "[Mergesort For Linked Lists](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html)" by Simon Tatham, the following version of `sortPolynomialTerms` uses a bottom-up merge sort:

```
void sortPolynomialTerms(struct Node **poly)
{
    /*
     * Bottom-up merge sort, based on:
     *
     * <https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.c>
     *
     * Original copyright notice for linked source:
     *
     * This file is copyright 2001 Simon Tatham.
     * 
     * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
     * obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
     * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
     * restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
     * copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or
     * sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
     * Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
     * conditions:
     * 
     * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
     * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
     * 
     * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
     * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
     * OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
     * NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL SIMON TATHAM BE LIABLE FOR
     * ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF
     * CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
     * CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
     * SOFTWARE.
     */
    struct Node *head;      /* head of merged list */
    unsigned int sublen;    /* maximum length of sub-list */

    head = *poly;
    if (!head) {
        /* The list is empty, so does not need sorting. */
        return;
    }

    /* Start with sub-lists of maximum length 1. */
    sublen = 1;
    while (1) {
        struct Node *tail;      /* tail of merged list */
        struct Node *p;         /* pointer to node in first sub-list */
        struct Node *q;         /* pointer to node in second sub-list */
        struct Node *e;         /* pointer to node to add to merged list */
        unsigned int plen;      /* length of first sub-list */
        unsigned int qlen;      /* maximum length of second sub-list */
        unsigned int merges;    /* number of sub-list merges done */
        unsigned int i;

        /*
         * Construct a new merge list by merging one or more pairs
         * of sorted sub-lists of length up to `sublen`.
         */
        p = head;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        merges = 0;
        while (p) {
            merges++;
            /* Step up to `sublen` places along from `p`. */
            q = p;
            plen = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < sublen; i++) {
                plen++;
                q = q->next;
                if (!q) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            qlen = plen;    /* upper bound on length of second sub-list */

            /*
             * Merge the two sub-lists onto the end of the new merge list.
             */
            while (plen || (qlen && q)) {
                /* Decide where the next element to merge comes from. */
                if (!plen || (qlen && q && compareTerms(p, q) < 0)) {
                    /* Take next element from second list `q`. */
                    e = q;
                    q = q->next;
                    qlen--;
                } else {
                    /* Take next element from first list `p`. */
                    e = p;
                    p = p->next;
                    plen--;
                }
                /* Add next element to the merged list. */
                if (tail) {
                    tail->next = e;
                } else {
                    head = e;
                }
                tail = e;
            }

            /* Advance to the next pair of sub-lists. */
            p = q;
        }
        /* Terminate the new merge list. */
        tail->next = NULL;

        /* Finish when no more than one pair of sub-lists needed merging. */
        if (merges <= 1) {
            break;
        }
        
        /* Double the maximum length of the sub-lists for the next merge. */
        sublen *= 2;
    }

    /* Update the link to the first node of the list. */
    *poly = head;
}
```

Comment: I made a bubble sort version of my own that works (Codeblocks) but gives me segmentation fault errors in another compiler. While I try your approach, please do check mine.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm sure you must have seen the `(a > b) - (a < b)` trick enough times before to know that it won't overflow?

Comment: Im curious with the way you compared the terms. Wouldn't it be the same but faster to do this instead? `return (term->powX*pow(10, 2)) + (term->powY*pow(10, 1)) + (term->powZ*pow(10, 0)`

Comment: I made a function `int degree(struct Node *term) {return (term->powX*pow(10, 2)) + (term->powY*pow(10, 1)) + (term->powZ*pow(10, 0));}` and I use that for comparing the terms.

Comment: It's a bit messy down here, but you can find the function in my original post.

Comment: @lambduh But what if the polynomial contained exponents greater than 9? Also `pow()` is relatively slow and uses floating point, although the compiler could optimize out the calls to `pow()`, replacing `pow(10, 2)` with `100.0`, etc.

Comment: Your code works for the given test cases, but there are hidden ones that it failed. I think there is a mistake in my implementation of your `compareTerms` in my `addPolynomials` function. In my understanding, if `compareTerms` > 0, `a` > `b` and the other way around? Am I right? You can check my code (adjusted based on your specification) in the original post.

Comment: `compareTerms` is returning a negative value (-1) if `a` < `b`, a positive value (1) if `a` > `b`, and 0 if they are equal. `sortPolynomialTerms` is sorting in descending order based on that. It could be true that `compareTerms` is not ordering `a` and `b` by the exactly the same criteria that the setter of the problem required.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute simplest way of sorting a linked list is to convert it to a regular list, use `qsort` and then convert back. Something like this:

```
// Converts a linked list to array
// 
// Assumes that memory is already allocated for dest and that src is a proper
// linked list where the last element has NULL assigned to ->next
void linkedListToArray(struct Node *dest, struct Node *src) {
    while(src) {
        *dest = src;
        dest++;
        src = src->next;
    }
}
```

You should redesign your code to be more modular. You should study implementations of linked lists in general, but you should really write a function similar to this:

```
void append(struct Node **list, int coeff, int px, int py, int pz) {
    struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    *node = (struct Node) {.coeff = coeff, .powX = px, .powY = py, .powZ = pz };

    if(*list == NULL) {
        *list = node;
    } else {
        while((*list)->next) (*list) = (*list)->next;
        (*list)->next = node;
    }
}
```

You should use it in `readPolynomial` but also in the function converting an array to a linked list.

```
void arrayToLinkedList(struct Node **list, struct Node *arr, size_t size) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        append(list, &arr[i]);
}
```

When you have the above, you just need to write the compare function for quicksort. Read the documentation about how that is done. And then you can do this:

```
struct Node *pol;
// Init code

struct Node *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * size); // Calculate size before somehow

linkedListToArray(arr, pol);
qsort(arr, size, sizeof *arr, cmp);
struct Node *newPol;
arrayToLinkedList(&newPol, arr);
```

Note that I have skipped all error checking to keep the code short.

#### Old answer. I misread the question, but OP mentioned they liked the answer in comments. The below says it is how to make a polynomial to standard form, but the question I'm really answering is how to normalize a polynomial.

To convert it to <strike>standard</strike> normalized form, you basically need to do two things

1. Find the term with highest degree
2. Divide all terms with the coefficient of the term with highest degree.

Determining the term with highest degree is ambiguous when dealing with more than one variable, since the degree simply is `Node::powX + Node::powY + Node::powZ`. But in any case, you would need to define a function that takes a whole polynomial and returns the node with highest degree according to some definition. Here is ONE way to do it:

```
int degree(struct Node *term) {
    return term->powX + term->powY + term->powZ;
}

struct Node *getTermWithHighestDegree(struct Node *pol) {
    struct Node *ret = pol;

    while(pol) {
        if(degree(pol) > degree(ret)) ret = pol;
        pol = pol->next;
    }
}
```

Then simply do:

```
void convertToNormalizedForm(struct Node *pol) {
    struct Node *term = getTermWithHighestDegree(pol);
    int coeff = term->coeff;

    while(pol) {
        pol->coeff /= coeff;
        pol = pol->next;
    }
}
```

Do however note that you might run into several issues because you're storing the coefficients as integers. You might want to change to a float type.